# Styling font on specific page on Wordpress website (Motela Theme)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I bought a paid theme (called the Motela theme) that annoyingly uses the Elementor "Headings" widget for all the paragraph text which makes it impossible to add any specific paragraph styling easily (adding bold text, etc.)

I've almost completed the website so it's too late to change the theme now. Support isn't included so I'm stuck on fixing two things:

a. I've used HTML for the Privacy Policy and Cookies Policy pages (because the text is too long to use the Headings widget). My problem is that when I try and use the "font-family" property, it doesn't pick up Open Sans AND the bullets are styled in a completely different font.

How can I style this whole page in Open Sans, including the bullets?

b. There is this annoying animation on the Home Page slider that moves the "Browse Services" and "Contact Us" buttons when your mouse moves over them. I have looked EVERYWHERE on the Slider Revolution plugin and I can't find where to disable it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Link to staging website](https://connections.hcbstaging.com/)

[image]